# Js шаблонизатор

Tags: шаблонизаторы, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь разобраться вот с этим [js шаблонизатором](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/templating), но не понимаю ни принцип работы, ни то, как и в каких случаях его можно использовать.

Прошу объяснить подробно, что делает этот скрипт, как его использовать и пример. Пример, который указан на сайте, у меня так и не получилось запустить, так как я не пониманию, где должны быть данные.

Answer (score 3):

Автор, посмотри на дату комментариев к той статье, они аж от 2008 года, эта статья морально устарела и с того времени появилось множество различных шаблонизаторов.

Лучше обрати внимание на такие шаблонизаторы, как [Jade](https://github.com/jadejs/jade), [Dust](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs), [SnakeSkin](https://github.com/kobezzza/Snakeskin)(один из самых новых и навороченных).

Comment: да я же с самым простым разобраться не могу, что мне с "навороченными" делать...

Comment: В доках к Snakeskin'у есть примеры, попробуй их повторить. Если не получится - пиши)